# Windows equivalent for running this docker code

Tags: docker, dockerfile

What is the windows equivalent of this code?

```
sudo docker pull ghcr.io/theislab/extended-single-cell-best-practices-container:latest
```

[Link to docker](https://github.com/theislab/extended-single-cell-best-practices-container)

I have tried running this command already in windows cmd:

> docker run ghcr.io/theislab/extended-single-cell-best-practices-container:latest

Comment: please paste the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce your problem,

```
docker run ghcr.io/theislab/extended-single-cell-best-practices-container:latest
```

works fine for me. Without the error messages debugging will be impossible. I can just give some Assumptions.

1. Do you have docker desktop installed? if not -> [Docker Desktop](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows)
2. Is the docker daemon running? to find out, try `docker ps` in the powershell. When the Answer to this is `error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.`, your daemon is probably not running -> Start docker desktop. The file to do so should be in a directory like this : `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe`

For further debugging I would need more information on the error Message. This kind of message would have been better as a comment, but I'm not allowed to write some because of my low reputation, sorry for that